# Build to parent folder with HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script

Tags: ant, build-script, html5boilerplate

When i try to build to the parent folder with HTML5 Boilerplate build script i get this message:

> Your dir.publish folder is set to ../ which could delete your entire site or worse.

Firstly, the build script doesn't delete any files, it just replaces them right?
Secondly, "or worse"? It's not like I'm googling google or mixing nitroglycerin here :(

Is there a work around?

EDIT:
I deleted this line in build.xml:

```
<equals arg1="${dir.publish}" arg2="../"/>
```

It works fine but i feel a bit dirty. Should i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the edit. I funked around in the build.xml and deleted this line:

```
<equals arg1="${dir.publish}" arg2="../"/>
```

I haven't had any problems yet but use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, I wrote that error message, sorry :( but there is an ant task (clean) in build script which is to delete the publish and intermediate folders. And if you set your publish folder to ../ you can imagine what can happen :)

Comment: Hehe, i'm staying away from that then.